# How to: A scenebreak in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm trying to write a novel using bookdown: HTML, EPUB, as well as PDF (pdfLaTeX). I'm using the indent mode, so paragraphs begin with an indent. I have the following custom LaTeX command, called `\scenebreak`, which:

1. Leaves an empty line between paragraphs when the scene changes within a chapter.
2. Introduces a ding, if the scene break is at the end of a page, or the beginning of a page.
3. Resets indent for the paragraph that follows the break (the paragraph that follows the break starts flush left).

Here's the LaTeX:

```
% scene breaks
\renewcommand{\pfbreakdisplay}{%
\scriptsize\ding{86}}
\newcommand{\scenebreak}{\pfbreak*\noindent}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\indent}}
```

When introducing the scenebreak in LaTeX, I call it so

```
Text here

\scenebreak

New scene begins here.
```

In HTML, this is how I've done it:

```
<div style='text-align:center;'>&#8226;</div>
```

I'm aware that a `block` in bookdown is like a LaTeX environment.

Is a similar setup possible with commands/macros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, but if you are trying to write out different content depending on the different output format, here is what you could do:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
knitr::asis_output(if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) {
  "\\scenebreak"
} else {
  "<div style='text-align:center;'>&#8226;</div>"
})
```
````

If you have to do this multiple times, create a function and call the function instead, e.g., insert this code chunk in the beginning of your book:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
scenebreak = function() {
  knitr::asis_output(if (knitr:::is_latex_output()) {
    "\\scenebreak"
  } else {
    "<div style='text-align:center;'>&#8226;</div>"
  })
}
```
````

Then use the function `scenebreak()` where a break is needed:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
scenebreak()
```
````

Comment: Hi Yihui, that’s kind of what I’m looking for. However, is there a single command kinda way to accomplish this? Because adding this for each scene break (my book has about twenty) would be a little…

Comment: Create a function in the beginning of your novel and call it wherever you need it.

Comment: I'm not an R programmer. Could you please point me to a tutorial that helps with creating a function in this context? Is [this](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/02-func-R/) a good one to go with?

Comment: It is certainly impractical for me to teach you R basics, and I don't know what would be a good tutorial for you. All I can do is to provide an answer to your specific question. BTW, I have updated my answer. If you still don't understand it, I'm out of ideas, and you have to wait for other people to give you a better answer..

Comment: Of course, I understand, and my intention wasn’t to learn to program with R, in that comment. I just needed a pointing-in-the-direction. Your edited answer does that. Thank you. I’ll try it out and mark it as answer if it works. I’ve upvoted the answer already.

Comment: Okay, glad to know that!

Comment: It needed a small change: an additional `\`. I've modified the answer to what works. Thanks, @YihuiXie!